# How to loop through the response text of JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file that contains object like that:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "feed": {

    },
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "",
            "author": ""

        },
        {
          "title": "",
           "author": ""
        },
        {
          "title": "",
           "author": ""
        }     
    ]
}
```

I want to loop through the items and get each item data like title and author.

The code I tried:

```
var json = $.getJSON({'url':"filejson" , 'async': false});
json = JSON.parse(json.responseText); 
$.each(json, function(index , item) {
     console.log(json[index]);
});
```

Comment: What happens when you do this? Does it give an error?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the sync version of it acts in a weird way,

```
var json = JSON.parse($.getJSON({'url':"filejson" , 'async': false}).responseText);
let items = json.items;
items.forEach(item=>{
    console.log(item.title, item.author);
})
```

As a sidenote, you should really not be using `async: false`.

Comment: I get this error "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: What does the `json` variable contain?

Comment: {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
   console.log(json[key])
})

// or if supported/polyfilled

Object.values(json).forEach(function(value) {
   console.log(value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()`:

```
data.map(d => ({title: d.title, author: d.author}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

```
var json = $.getJSON({'url':"filejson" , 'async': false});
json = JSON.parse(json.responseText); 
$.each(json.items, function(key , value) {
     console.log(value['title'] + " : "+ value['author']);
});
```